# Best Practice for Returning Java Future from Library

Tags: java, future

I am working on a Java library that implements the Jump Point Search algorithm. There are two exposed methods you can call to run the search. A synchronous one and one that returns a Java `Future` of the results.

```
public Future<Queue<T>> findPath(T start, T goal) {
    FutureTask<Queue<T>> future = new FutureTask<>(() -> findPathSync(start, goal));
    future.run();
    return future;
}
```

What I would like to know is, what is the best practice in this case. Should the library actually run the `FutureTask` and return the `Future`, or should it return a `FutureTask` and the end user would have to know that the Task has not actually been executed yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Gotta agree with Doug.  I'd prefer a Future, not a FutureTask.  For the latter, use a better method name and also specify the return type as FutureTask if you are going to give the user something that needs to be sent to an Executor.  **IF** you think the API needs a FutureTask.  I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really speak for a "best practice" but, as a user, if I call a method my default assumption is that it's triggered something - that it's initiated execution - and usually the "construct only" paradigm is reserved for the builder pattern or a factory.

So the above code you have is the behaviour I would expect, and what I feel I see most often if not always, even in other systems (i.e. Node.js)

Comment: and I would add, if you are going to defer execution I would recommend that you signal this to readers of your code/API with appropriate naming conventions - `findPath` sounds like it does just that.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the input. Definitely makes a lot of sense when you word it like that.